# How to change the position of view after a translate animation using NineOldAndroids?

Tags: android, animation, nineoldandroids

I tried searching around and found that you have to set a listener to change the actual position of the view when the animation ends. But the thing is, I don't know how I can get the end values from the ObjectAnimator I am using.

Isn't there an easy way to do this aside from setting listeners to all of my Animators, there are like 9 of them. Something like a `setFillAfter(true)` I always see that but I can't seem to find what Animator object uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you have to have an AnimatorListener attached to the Animators that will do this for you. But that is too much for me because I have multiple Animators. So what I did, I positioned them on the layout in what they would be after the end animation, then I made the Animator to animate from the start position to their end position. That way I don't have to fret over the actual positions of the views